# Netbeans Platform application installer

Tags: netbeans-platform

New version of NetBeans IDE 6.9 comes with option to generate installer for Netbeans Platform application. I am wondering if it is possible to modify it. 
I want to create installer with bundled Java, which is installed if user doesn't have java already.

Answer (score 2):

There was some communications about this on [Geertjans blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/) a little while back. See [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/customizing_the_netbeans_platform_installer) for the initial post, and [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/installing_the_jre_via_an) for the follow up which provides detailed instructions on how to achieve this.